# using jquery data table but image is not showing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using jquery datatable but the image is not showing  please help me to solve this issue

```js
$("#users").DataTable({

  "ajax": {

    "url": "/tbProducts/LoadData",
    "type": "GET",
    "datatype": "json"
  },
  "columns": [{
      "data": "BrandName"
    },
    {
      "data": "ProductName",
      "searchable": false
    },
    {
      "data": "ProductCode",
      "searchable": false
    },
    {
      "data": "ProductDescript",
      "searchable": false
    },
    {
      "data": "ProductImage",
      "render": function(data) {


        return "<img src='" + data + "' />";
      }
    },
    {
      "data": "ProductPrice",
      "searchable": false
    },
    {
      "data": "ProductBeforePrice",
      "searchable": false
    },
    {
      "data": "ProductAvailability",
      "searchable": false
    },
    {
      "data": "subcategory",
      "searchable": false
    }

  ]
});
```

Comment: Check the path of the image `src` and value of your `data` variable. If the path is correct, try defining the width and height of the image element.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Sir path is correct and i also define width and height but still not working

Comment: From a [deleted comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66541850/using-jquery-data-table-but-image-is-not-showing/66541887#comment117634313_66541887) by [somi shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14889199/somi-shah): *thanks Alot its because of this ~ root symbol it happens thanks for the guide*